# Abscissa of absolute convergence of a Dirichlet series

Tags: convergence-divergence, inverse, dirichlet-series

I'd like some help to prove the following theorem :

> Let $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{g(n)}{n^s}$ be two Dirichlet series with respective abscissas
>   of absolute convergence $\alpha_f$ and $\alpha_g$ ($\alpha_f, \alpha_g \neq -\infty$). Then the abscissa of convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{f*g(n)}{n^s}$ is :
>
> - $\max(\alpha_f, \alpha_g)$ if $\alpha_f \neq \alpha_g$ ;
> - less than or equal to $\alpha$ if $\alpha_f = \alpha_g = \alpha$
>
> where $f*g$ refers to the Dirichlet convolution of $f$ and $g$.

The result is to be proved in an exercise from this book [(exercise 9 page 259)](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5Lp-tGZR25sC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The statement of the book is probably buggy, I had to modify a few details for it to be plausible (for instance, replacing $\min$ by $\max$ and "greater than" by "less than").

I need a proof of the first point (case $\alpha_f \neq \alpha_g$) of the theorem. I'd prefer proofs not making use of complex analysis, since I don't know about it.

My ultimate goal is to prove that if $f$ is invertible (for Dirichlet convolution) and $\alpha_f \neq -\infty$, then $\alpha_{f^{-1}} \leq \alpha_f$.

Comment: PSA: [Here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/191859) it is shown that the assertion in the book is wrong.