# Properties of Dirichlet Inverse Series.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, analytic-functions, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

Let $F(n) = \sum f(n)n^{-s}$ that converges absolutely for $\sigma  > \sigma_a$, where $f(1) \not= 0$. We may define the Dirichlet series, 
$G(s) := \sum f^{-1}(n)n^{-s}$, where $f^{-1}$ is the *Dirchlet inverse* of $f$, satisfiying $f * f^{-1}(n) = [\frac{1}{n}]$.

I was wondering if 
$$ \text{ $\sum f^{-1}(n)n^{-s}$ converges absolutely for $\sigma > \sigma_a$ } $$

Comment: The abscissa of absolute convergence of $1/F$ [can be different](https://mathoverflow.net/a/191859) from the abscissa of absolute convergence of $F$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show that $f^{-1}(n)$ is itself a Dirichlet character, then $L(s,f^{-1})$ becomes a Dirichlet series which will definitely converge for $\Re(s)>1$ (Apostol, eq. (2), p. 224). You may then be able to use something like Theorem 2.8 (Apostol, p.30) and Theorem 11.1 (p.225) to help determine $\sigma_{a'}$ and possibly $a'=a$. But as mentioned in the comments the abscissa of convergence can be different.

Comment: @Daniel & Antinous: Thanks, but then how does the proof in this theorem, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369463/dirichlet-series-as-exponential-apostol-pg-238 even make sense - the fact that we can take series of $1/F$?