# Logarithm of a Dirichlet series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I am currently struggling to understand Section 11.9 in Tom Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, where he talks about taking the logarithm of a Dirichlet series.

The idea is that we have some Dirichlet series $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_nn^{-s}$ with $f(1)\neq 0$ and

1. $F(s)$ is absolutely convergent
2. $F(s) \neq 0$

for any $s$ with $\mathfrak{R}(s)>\sigma_0$.

Apostol says that we can then always find some Dirichlet series $G(s)$ that is also absolutely convergent for $\mathfrak{R}(s)>\sigma_0$ and fulfils $e^{G(s)} = F(s)$ for any such $s$, and that $$G(s) = \ln f(1) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(f' * f^{-1})(n)}{\ln n} n^{-s}$$
where $f^{-1}$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $f$ and $f'(n) = f(n) \ln n$, i.e. they correspond to the multiplicative inverse and the negative derivative of $F$.

However, if I am not missing anything here, I think all of this only works if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'(n) n^{-s}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{-1}(n) n^{-s}$ converge absolutely, but I don't see why they should, in general.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369463/theorem-11-14-apostol-pg-238-need-explanation) is strongly related, perhaps a duplicate. If we additionally choose $\sigma_0$ such that the Dirichlet series of $f^{-1}$ converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re} s > \sigma_0$, everything works as written. The question is whether the convergence is always absolute on the domain specified by Apostol, or whether absolute convergence can occur only on a strictly smaller domain.

Comment: You're right, I think this is a duplicate. I searched for a long time but did not come across that question.

Comment: It's not easy to find the right search terms, unless one knows which question one is looking for and remembers a few helpful things. Like the author of the question or an answer to it.